# GSAP - TweenMax : TweenMax.getAllTweens() returns objects instead of TweenMax instance

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I have get all TweenMax instance from a page.

So I use :

`TweenMax.getAllTweens()`

This works if the tweens are declared like this :

`TweenMax.to` or `TweenMax.formTo` or whatever but if the tweens are nested in a TimelineMax / Lite, `TweenMax.getAllTweens()` return an **array of objects** instead of my desired **array of TweenMax tweens**. So I can't use TweenMax methods on them.

I tryed to declare TweenMax instances, store them in variables and add them to TimelineMax like this :

```
var tween = TweenMax.to('selector', {x: 100})
new TimelineMax().add(tween)
```

This solution is working but the following :

```
new TimelineMax().to('selector', {x: 100})
```

Doesn't work.

**Do you have an idea of how I could deal with this issue and get all tweens instances ?**

Not sure to be understandable, don't hesitate to ask me questions.

My issue can be tested on https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-scrollmagic-tutorial/. Open console and type TweenMax.getAllTweens()

Comment: Shouldn't `TweenMax.getAllTweens()[0]` give you a TweenMax instance? Can't you loop over the array like this and write your code?

Answer (score -1):

`getChildren()` on the timeline instance should return you what you want. Find details on link.

https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax/getChildren()

Here is also a codepen for your pleasure

https://codepen.io/teejayhh/pen/rdKQxV